# SQL: Different calculation for each line based on a calculation saved in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with payment terms and I also would like to save the calculation in each line, to make use of it in the selection.

The goal is to have a selection of all payment terms as well as the calculated date based on a parameter. My question is: How to get the calulation result for each line to be displayed in a column in the result(table)? I have no idea :/

We use MS sql-server-2018.

Example
Source table: [table_payment_terms]

```
ID | payment term | calculation           | description
1  | d7           | date + 7              | 7 days
2  | d14          | date + 14             | 14 days
3  | m14          | nextmonths(date) + 6  | 7th of next month
```

Parameter: 01.01.2020

statment might be something like:

```
SELECT 'payment term', 
       function(description(parameter)) AS 'calculated date', 'description' 
FROM [table_payment_terms]
```

Result:

```
payment term | calculated date | description
d7           | 08.01.2020      | 7 days
d14          | 15.01.2020      | 14 days
m14          | 07.02.2020      | 7th of next month
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You will have to parse the string yourself. E.g. something alongthe lines of `select :some_base_date + case when calculation like 'nextmonth%' then interval 1 month else interval 0 month end + ...`. That may become quite tricky. Don't use single quotes for names by the way, they are meant for string literals.

Comment: It is a mssql database. My hope was that I can put everything into a sql statement.

The calculation is different for each line, those 3 examples are just the easy once.

Comment: Is it all single-character prefixes? Surely the list of payment terms isn't so large that a `case` expression wouldn't  work.

Comment: There about 100 different payment terms. Not sure if a case expression would be still a good choice.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 1):

This is an entirely non-trivial bit of functionality that you are looking to implement.

In essence, if you want to do this in SQL, you are going to have to create a scalar-valued function that takes a date parameter and then your function description as a second parameter (assuming that the only possible variable input would be a single date).

Within that function, you are going to have to parse your function description based on whatever grammar rules you have defined and calculate your output accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed it "just" a scalar-valued function with 2 parameters, one is the 'calculation' and one is the 'date'.

Somehow I thought is more complex. I havn't thought about using the calculation as a 2nd parameter.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to pass dynamic SQL to a scalar function and have it executed?

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi - I believe that this would be possible calling sp_executesql  and would be one way of doing it.  Care would need to be taken for possible sql injection though.

Comment: @Paddy good Point! I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

To store the calculation you could use direct conversions of the system datepart literals (reserved strings).  For example:

```
CASE @DatePart
   WHEN 'ns'  THEN DATEDIFF(ns, @EndDate, @StartDate) /* this is just taken an example */
   WHEN 'mcs' THEN DATEDIFF(mcs,@EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'ms'  THEN DATEDIFF(ms, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'ss'  THEN DATEDIFF(ss, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'mi'  THEN DATEDIFF(mi, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'hh'  THEN DATEDIFF(hh, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'dd'  THEN DATEDIFF(dd, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'ww'  THEN DATEDIFF(ww, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'mm'  THEN DATEDIFF(mm, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'qq'  THEN DATEDIFF(qq, @EndDate, @StartDate)
   WHEN 'yy'  THEN DATEDIFF(yy, @EndDate, @StartDate)
END
```

Then to calculate the result you could use a daterange function (like this [one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/a-daterange-table-valued-function)) or do it yourself to dynamically construct the computed date when you need it.  I would recommend not to store the calculated value but to store the translated system literals and the datetime offsets.